# How to Check if Address Bar of Browser is Active/InActive

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

we are just removed the address bar using Window.Open(....).
But now to we need to check if on each page whether address bar is active/on, If Address bar is on/Active we need to redirect to default page.

> We Should Not Allow to access few pages with
>   AddressBar ON/ACTIVE.

Any Help regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sounds like a strange phishing sort of request. How about an iFrame or ajaxing the page into a div? It is a) highly unlikely you can tell if the address bar is acive and b) you cannot turn it off in Firefox anymore

Answer (score 2):

> We Should Not Allow to access Certain parts of the pages with AddressBar ON/ACTIVE.

You *might* be able to determine how much space is available to you using `window.availHeight` or similar, but this idea is doomed anyway:
 Removing the address bar is no longer possible in most modern browsers for phishing reasons.

Comment: @sandeep as said, it's no longer possible to disable the address bar in most browsers in the first place. What browsers are you testing this in?

Comment: i am using IE7 &8, Chrome, Safari, FireFox

Comment: @sandeep - I don't believe you can hide the address bar in any of these browsers.

Comment: @Kobi My Idea is like this after login i il make use of "window.open("/SetUp/ManagePlaces.aspx", "one", "left=100, top=100, width=300, " + "height=300, location=no, menubar=no, resizable=no, " + "scrollbars=no, status=no, titlebar=no, toolbar=no");" and redirect to other page so tat all navigations from that page il occur with address Bar NOT ACTIVE. But some how i need to check if address bar is active in PageLoad

Comment: @sandeep but what you show will not work in IE8, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Have you tried it? Do you by "not active" mean "Not visible"?

Comment: @sandeep - Put aside your question about detecting if the address bar is visible - were you even able to hide it in the first place? See also this question: [How should a developer reject impossible requirements?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120872/how-should-a-developer-reject-impossible-requirements)

Comment: @Kobi Ingnore my question. Is there any way to get Window's "menubar" property value?